# Is function a discrete type in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I can identify the following types in JavaScript:

```
number, string, boolean, object, null and undefined
```

But, is `function` a discrete type, or is it an instance of `object`?

Comment: Functions are instances of the `Function` constructor. They're objects with special runtime-supported characteristics (like, being functions).

Comment: Also `typeof` considers `null` to be of type `Object`, and `undefined` really isn't a type at all.

Comment: So the return value of `typeof` correspond to a superset of the types in the language?

Comment: Personally I think `typeof` is somewhat broken. A better tool to use is the `.toString()` function on the `Object` prototype: `({}).toString.call(yourValue)` gives you a slightly cumbersome but less weird result than `typeof`.

Comment: `undefined` is not an `object` and is not one of the other types, so... it is a type of its own?

Comment: Well everything that's not a scalar type - numbers, booleans, and strings - that's not `null` or `undefined` is an object (actually the *values* involved are *references* to the objects - objects are never directly "values").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functions in javascript are inherited from Object. You can try the following :

```
var my_func = function(){};
console.log(my_func instanceof Object); // prints true
console.log(my_func instanceof Function); // also prints true
```

The same is true for Array.